# Real World application of Topological Quantum Field Theory

Tags: experimental-physics, topological-field-theory, topological-order

What is a "killer-app" for the formalism of topological quantum field theory in "established real world physics"?

To be more precise, I'm looking for an actual physical experiment, state of matter or something alike, together with a article that well describes it
by a topological quantum field theory.

I'm, in particular, not looking for hypothesized physics like string theory, just for something that already has been observed.

Comment: Seek out Floer Homology and Sir Michael Atiyah's seminal paper on *New invariants for manifolds of dimensions 3 and 4*.

Comment: Can you please be a little more precise. What physical system do they talk about? As a mathematician, I'm very aware of the importance in mathematics, but it is kind of hard these days to separate established physics from pure math or hypothesized physics. Especially when the term "quantum" is involved.

Comment: The physical system is spacetime since TQFT is a QFT that computes topological invariants; in this instance if you like; one can consider the topological invariants of smooth four-manifolds.

Comment: I think we talk about different things here. I would say space time is the killer app for general relativity. I mean what physical system is best described by TQFT but poorely without. Like a topological insulator ect. I mean spacetime is likely contractable, therfore trivial in this consideration.  I think I'm looking for a more practical answer, since I'm posting at physics not at math-forum.

Comment: But it's funny that even in a physics forum, people tend to favor abstract mathematical answers over practical ones.

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus In my opinion it is far more common to listen the words "higher category", "cobordism" and "homology" in a theoretical physics department than in the whole $($math $\setminus$ $($number theory $\cup$ algebraic geometry$))$ department... :-D

Comment: As I said, I'm not a physicist. But in my naive understanding of physics, there should be a real world problem for this kind of math, that renders the hole theory as physics, not 'just' as math. But on the other side, then string theory couldn't in large extends, be called physics, too. Maybe that's a anomaly of our times... Anyway, I think this just refelcts my concerns about the ongoing mixture of physics and hypothesized physics, to the point where a non expert has problems to seperate fiction from reality :D

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice pedagogical review of the quantum Hall effect that can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0457). They explain (sketchily) how to derive an effective action describing the bulk of a quantum Hall fluid, which is a topological quantum field theory: Chern-Simons (CS) theory. The main physics which can be gleaned from this is that any defects in the bulk of the fluid could be anyonic quasiparticles. However, to my knowledge these defects are not observed in experiments; instead, the anyonic quasiparticles live on the edges of the sample. So this is hardly a "killer application", actually the CS theory just tells you that nothing interesting really happens in the bulk.

Of course, this review is pretty old and I expect that the state-of-the-art has changed considerably since then.

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed along the line of what I'm searching for. .. Are saying that the observation of the anyons is different from the Chern-Simon prediction  in this example?

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus Yes, the fractional charge-carriers that are detected in transport experiments on quantum Hall samples are edge modes, they do not live in the bulk. However, I believe that the charges and statistics of the bulk theory excitations are probably related to/the same as those of the corresponding CFT on the boundary.

Answer (score 4):

Topological Quantum Field Theory (TQFT) is the low energy effective theory for the topological ordered states in real world, such as FQH states. In fact, the name "topological order" was motived from the term "Topological Quantum Field Theory". [See *Topological Orders in Rigid States*, Xiao-Gang Wen, Int. J. Mod. Phys. B4, 239 (1990)   http://dao.mit.edu/~wen/pub/topo.pdf].

We also have a modern mathematical summary in  [arXiv:1405.5858](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5858)
    *Braided fusion categories, gravitational anomalies, and the mathematical framework for topological orders in any dimensions* which point out that:

Topological orders in $n$ space-time dimension = unitary $n$-categories with one object = $n$ dimensional fully extented TQFT = gravitational anormalies in one lower dimensions

Since topological orders describe gapped quantum phases in real world, $n$-categories, fully extented TQFT, gravitational anormalies all have connection to real word quantum states of matter, such as FQH state. The spins in 2+1D TQFT can be measured by edge tunneling IV curve or RT curve.

Comment: Yes thanks. That is exactly what I wanted to see. Personally I find this a little more interesting then the quantum hall effect. However I mark the hall effect as the answer, since I would say, it is a little more "the" archetypical example, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hello. I am looking for a reference to start studying tqft. Do you know any good pedagogical one? thanks