# Relationship between TQFTs and gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

The motivation for this question comes from observing that the toric code model has the properties of a TQFT (robust ground state degeneracy) and of a $\mathbb Z_2$ gauge theory (local spin flips don't change the Hamiltonian). The question is, is there any general relationship between TQFTs and gauge theories: does one imply the other, or can they be related in some limit, say at zero temperature?

Comment: A gauge theory is not necessarily a TFT.

Comment: related: [The system is topological; so what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401788/84967).